# javascript add variable time to date and time

Tags: javascript, datetime

I need to create a new date/time string based on some variabeles. But I'm not sure how I could do this, I've been searching a bit but can't really find a solution.

```
    var fields = 5; //Fields can vary from 1 tot 999;
    var currenttime = $("#serverTime").text().split(":"); //format: 23:02:59
    var timetoadd = 5*30 // 150 minutes

    var totalseconds = currenttime[0]*3600 + currenttime[1]*60 + currenttime[2] + timetoadd*60;

    var currentdate = new Date();
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type cast it:

```
var totalseconds = parseInt(currenttime[0])*3600 + parseInt(currenttime[1])*60 + parseInt(currenttime[2]) + timetoadd*60;
```

To get new date:

```
var t = new Date(1970,0,1);
console.log(t.setSeconds(totalseconds));
```

Comment: The code to get totalseconds works. My problem is that I don't know how to get the new date and time when adding totalseconds.